# PHP download file pegando todo código html em vez de conteúdo do arquivo

Tags: php, html, download

Bom, como o titulo implica.

Meu código está baixando todo o html da minha página em vez de apenas o conteúdo que escrevo no arquivo.

```
if(isset($_GET['cpf'])){
                //config
                $namefile = $_GET['nome'].'.txt';
                $content = $_GET['cpf'];

                //save file
                $file = fopen($namefile, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                fwrite($file, $content);

                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($namefile).'"');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: '. filesize($file));
               //   ob_clean(); 
                flush();
                readfile($file);

                fpassthru($file);
                fclose($file);
                exit();
            }
```

já olhei mais de 10 tópicos diferentes, mas nenhum referente ao meu problema.

O `ob_clean()` apaga tudo, baixo um arquivo em branco.

E sim, to tentando baixar um arquivo `txt`

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou colocar um echo antes desse fwrite? Assim:

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp